# Applying Hensel's lemma

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to prove that the following equation:

$$(x^2 - 2) (x^2 - 17) (x^2 - 2\cdot 17) = 0$$

has solutions $ \pmod{p^k}$ for all $p,k$. It's easy to find nonzero solutions $ \pmod{2,17} $ - and for all other primes it follows from the fact that either $ 2 $ or $ 17 $ is a square residue $ \pmod{p} $, or their product is. Now I'm trying to use Hensel's lemma to lift the $\mod p$ solutions to solutions $\mod p^k$ for $k=2,3\ldots$ - but how do I prove that

$$ \frac{d}{dx} (x^2 - 2) (x^2 - 17) (x^2 - 2\cdot 17) \neq 0 \pmod{p} \text{ for some } x \text{ satisfying the equation?} $$

Thanks in advance - I would appreciate some help

Comment: Wait, what ring are you trying to solve this in? Hensel's lemma only works on local rings with some other mild hypotheses.

Comment: I'm trying to prove there is a solution $ \mod {p^k}$ for $ k = 1,2, \dots $

Comment: @AdamHughes, problem 121 on page 79 of Gouvea, $p$-adic Numbers. Presumably, several other  books.

Comment: @Jytug I know that, but mod $p^k$ in what ring? $\Bbb Z$, for example is not Henselian, but $\Bbb Z_p$ is. It doesn't really make sense to talk about Hensel's lemma for multiple primes, since the ring is local.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks, I'll download a copy and see if I can get the context from there * grumble *

Comment: @WillJagy The hint there is that for $ p \neq 17,2 $ it's a straght application of Hensel's lemma. I can agree as long as it's obvious that the derivative doesn't vanish - an I can't think of a way to justify it

Comment: @AdamHughes, this is a pretty well known example of local to global failing with just one variable and not homogeneous. This is in contrast to Hasse-Minkowski on quadratic forms. The other item, very famous, is Selmer's example (1957), there are no nonzero rational solutions to $3 x^3 + 4 y^3 + 5 z^3=0,$ despite nontrivial $p$-adic solutions for all $p \leq \infty.$ Oh, Gouvea specifies, no roots in $\mathbb Q$ despite solutions in all $\mathbb Q_p,$ this being for the $2,17,34$ thing.

Comment: @WillJagy I always use the 3,4,5 example myself, but mostly I was trying to make sure we were on the same page--the op and I--since that's a critical bit of info to solve the problem. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @AdamHughes, this may be peripheral, but $34$ is the smallest number where $x^2 - 34 y^2 = -1$ is impossible in $\mathbb Z,$ despite $x^2 - 2 y^2 = -1$ and $x^2 - 17 y^2 = -1$ being easy in integers. The first odd (not square) number that does that is $205,$ as $x^2 - 205 y^2 \neq -1$ in $\mathbb Z.$ Next odd is $221.$

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could explain precisely the way the lemma works in that case - nobody seems to care about the derivative

Comment: @AdamHughes I'm sorry, but your edit is terribly irrelevant to my question - considering the fact that I have no idea what $ \mathbb{Q}_p $ means. The formulation that I know of Hensel's lemma doesn't use $ p $-adic numbers either

Comment: @Jytug This is very surprising, but I suppose it's conceivable someone is just doing a modular lifting without noting that's equivalent to a $\Bbb Q_p$ lifting (which is the main purpose of Hensel's lemma). I'll fix it.

Comment: Well, actually I believe the Chinese Remainder Theorem allows this problem to give some interesting results (interesting to me at least, though people more advanced in mathematics might find it silly). I'll return to this page once I get to know something more about $ p $-adic analysis. I appreciate your comments

Comment: Jytug, in that case, what is your source for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every prime $p>3$ we have that $G=\mathbb{Z}/(p^k\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a cyclic group and: 
$$ |G| = (p-1)\,p^{k-1}. $$

If $p\neq 17$, then both $2,17$ and $2\cdot 17$ belong to $G$.

For every $g\in G$, we have that the Legendre symbol $ g^{\frac{|G|}{2}} $ can be only $\pm 1$, and it equals one iff $g$ is a square in $G$. Since the Legendre symbol is multiplicative, we have that at least one element among $2,17,34$ is a square in $G$.

<sup>Footnote: The square of the Legendre symbol $g^{\frac{|G|}{2}}$ is one, and the equation $x^2-1=0$ has the same number of solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$ and in $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k\mathbb{Z})^*$ by Hensel's lemma. The first group is a field, hence the only square roots of one in $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k\mathbb{Z})^*$ are $\pm 1$.</sup>

Comment: This is good, so +1, but it's also incomplete IMO, you should address $p=17$ (easy) and $p=2$ (almost as easy).